# Can we use Win2D in a .NET Core (3.1) project?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, nuget, win2d

I searched for NuGet package for Win2d and only found something for UWP.
Can we use Win2D in a WPF Core(3.1) project?

Comment: Unlikely due to dependencies. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes you can. If there are no direct dependency, you can create a UWP window that plays with Win2D, and use its handle to inject its content into a XAML asset for WPF core. You'll need to work a bit in term of interop (use the native user32.dll etc).

Comment: @TheBatman, I want to do a graphic app which should have a similar look ar a uml diagram with thousands of graphics.

Comment: @Soleil, seems very complicated...

Comment: @EricOuellet I think It is simpler than injecting DX12 win32 into WPF. It seems that you can do this with XAML islands too: https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/23/net-core-3-use-uwp-controls-in-wpf-with-xaml-islands/. Hence you got at least two alternatives here. I you would like to give a try to the UWP into WPF injection, let me know.